# Ampscript 'onclick or ng-click'-like functionality?

Tags: click, ampscript

I'm new to Ampscript and I've created a page in html and set variables within Ampscript.  I am now trying to get an ampscript function to run once a user clicks a html button.  Is this possible??? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  AMPScript is a server-side language, not client-side.  It'll only be processed before the page displayed in your browser.

BTW, you'll find a lot more Salesforce Marketing Cloud help over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/), specifically with the [AMPScript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tag.